# Pegman icon of google.maps.StreetViewPanorama goes behind marker on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using external library MarkerWithLabel to create markers on map. Also marker icon used is font-awesome icons. I am also using google.maps.StreetViewPanorama to display street view of marker. But there is one issue, when I drag pegman icon and hover over marker the pegman icon is displayed behind marker but I want pegman icon to display above marker. I tried to set z-index of marker but no use. For better understanding I have create example in (jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t4v8nhoq/11/) .

```
var map;
var panorama;
var streetView;

function initialize() {

map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.976, -2.021),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("pano")
    );

map.setStreetView(panorama);

streetView = map.getStreetView();

streetView.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(54.976, -2.021) );

var icon = {
        html: '<span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i></span>'
    };
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.975, -2.020),
    icon: ' ',
    labelContent: icon.html,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(95, 20),
    labelClass: "labels",
    labelStyle: {
        opacity: 0.75
    },
    zIndex: null,
    map: map
});

}
```

Please look into this link. Take the pegman icon over marker. Please give me some solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can base with this code.

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.975, -2.020),
map: map}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(
marker1,
'click',
function(){ document.getElementById("listener").innerHTML +=
"marker clicked<br>";
});
}
```

Or check this page http://jsfiddle.net/spiderplant0/brkca/.